# Need help positioning and margin achartengine

Tags: android, charts, position, achartengine, donut-chart

I'm trying to make a doughnut chart with title in right aligment and chart in center of the linear layout.

this my render code:

```
    DefaultRenderer renderer = buildCategoryRenderer(colors);
    renderer.setShowLabels(true);
    renderer.setInScroll(true);
    renderer.setChartTitle("BEST TITLE IN THE WORLD");
    renderer.setZoomEnabled(false);
    renderer.setPanEnabled(false);// Disable User Interaction
    renderer.setScale((float) 1.3);
    renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    renderer.setStartAngle(0);
    //didn't work: margins - an array containing the margin size values,
    //in this order: top, left, bottom, right
    int[] margins = {150,0,0,0};
    renderer.setMargins(margins);
    //if I set to false, title disappear
    renderer.setShowLabels(true);
    renderer.setShowLegend(false);

    MultipleCategorySeries categorySeries = new MultipleCategorySeries(
            "CONTENUTI");
    categorySeries.add(labels, values);

    donutGraph = ChartFactory.getDoughnutChartView(this,
            categorySeries, renderer);
    donutGraph.setLeft(10);
    donutGraph.setOnClickListener(this);
    parent.addView(donutGraph);

    donutGraph.repaint();
```

this my xml code (only donut chart):

```
    <!-- layout donut -->
    <LinearLayout
             android:id="@+id/pie_chart"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="0dip"
             android:layout_weight="0.5"
             android:layout_margin="10dp"
             android:orientation="horizontal"
             android:background="#aadd66">
    </LinearLayout>
```

this is the result:

[image: result]

my questions:

1. How can I change the origin of the donut? Should I do this with DefaultRenderer object or with GraphicalView?
2. how can I right align the title? (if it possible).
3. How can I show the title but not the label?

If you have a good tutorial, please tell me: I have to make a another scatter plot.
Thank you very much!

Comment: You have to change lib code for ur requirements .

Comment: No one of my questions can be answered without change lib code?

Comment: At least this one, I can tell what to change .

Comment: Now I'm writing code, this graphics improvements I'm going to make after finishing code. Can you write where I have to change code as answer of this question, thus I can mark your as right answer? I will try it as soon as possible. Thank you very much

Comment: @Tenaciousd93 hey can u help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23749304/radius-of-doughnut-chart-in-achartengine

Comment: @Monicka I change my project into a pie because donut isn't clickable... btw my old old code with donut is there: http://pastebin.com/k7trDbdf for a week, if it can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**2.how can I right align the title? (if it possible).**

**3.How can I show the title but not the label?**

Make these changes in `drawTitle()` method of `RoundChart.java`

```
 public void drawTitle(Canvas canvas, int x, int y, int width, Paint paint) {
//    if (mRenderer.isShowLabels()) {
      paint.setColor(mRenderer.getLabelsColor());
      paint.setTextAlign(Align.LEFT);
      paint.setTextSize(mRenderer.getChartTitleTextSize());
      drawString(canvas, mRenderer.getChartTitle(), x  ,
          y + mRenderer.getChartTitleTextSize(), paint);    //REMOVE "+ width / 2"
//    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try this code soon as possible. I will let you know if it works